# How to force compositor nodes to execute?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

Whenever I add certain compositor nodes after a render is done, it doesn't execute these automatically without re-rendering (By automatically I mean whenever a change to the node setup is made, regardless the state of the rendering process).

I'm specifically referring to the ''**file output**'' node here.

[image]

Is there a way to force this node to execute?
(Automatically and/or manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out there is no easy way (if any) to trigger either compositing or file-save in both the GUI and the Python API. Or at least not without re-rendering the image.

Based on this [anwser](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55618/37739) I made an extension that does the following:

- Make a new dummy render layer
- Disable all scene layers
- Render the dummy layer (and only that layer)

As a byproduct it will re-composite all your render layers and thus re-trigger the compositing of your image.

Afterwards it will delete the dummy render layer.

To make it easy I made it so that you can search for "recompose" by hitting space or hitting the "Recompose" button in the Node Editor when you're inside the Compositing Node Tree.

You can find the addon here: http://cloud.webvi.be/index.php/s/NYbHNlrVX4ZikXn

Comment: Good answer. One thing would you put the addon on github? I don't like random file sharing sites. (plus the link is not permanent)

Comment: @Wouter The link is dead, basically rendering this question effectively empty. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.

Answer (score 2):

Generally Ctrl Shift click on the last node connect the viewer and force a refresh of the compositor nodes. If it fails, you can use an UV editor window, choose "viewer node" and save the result as image, without a new rendering.

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for your response.
Refreshing the nodes isn't the problem.
Also, this is just an example. My real workflow requires an autosave on multiple file outputs. This would be really tedious to do manually with the F3 ''save as image'' command.

Comment: Ah, ok! It can be useful for others users.