# Blender 2.8 : how to render selected file output node in compositor without having to re-render the scene?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Is it possible ? it's silly if i want to just render a **file output** node then i have to rende the whole scene. Why there's no render button in this node so i can render  only that node ? Also is there any way i can render batch multiple selected **file output** or **render layers** nodes ?

Right now, to render multiple **render layers** node, i have to click the render button on each of those nodes one by one.

Comment: You can save all layers and passes to a single or multiple OpenEXR multilayer file using the file output node. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53300/combining-exr-files/53301#53301 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33884/how-can-i-add-inputs-to-a-file-output-node

Comment: and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55558/saving-compositor-file-output-without-rerendering

Comment: exr is not what i'm looking for, If i change selection then it means i have to re-edit the exr over and over again. i simpy want to render whatever output i select (pipe it into a file output node). I just want to create some custom texture in compositing without have to go to photoshop. So at least, a render button on each file output node will help a bit. Even better i can select multlple output node and simply hit a hotkey to run batch render. Sometime if i just want to blur and color correct a texture , i should be able to do it in compositing without have to open external app.