# Is there a way to get back to renders that are in "Render Slots" without having to preform a render?

Tags: rendering

Is there a way to get back to the Render Slot Dropdown Menu (That already has renders in it) "without" having to make another render? This would be during a single session of Blender.

Comment: do you mean if you rendered something, and then rendered something else on the same slot, would you lose the previous render?

Comment: @MattTheWaffleCat - No. I mean if I render more than once to a Render Slot(s) potentially up to eight and then I leave the Render Slots to edit but then I want to check/reference the Render Slots again BEFORE another render so I can make additional edits.

Comment: @cegaton - I get it thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the question might not really be about render slots but rather about where to find your renders if you can't see them. If so:

There are two ways to get back to your render.
Using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>F11</kbd> Will bring up the render window without re-rendering (<kbd>F12</kbd> does the same but also re-renders). You can then follow steps 4 to 6 below if you render isn't visible.
Or, referring to the picture below:

1. Using the button in the bottom left of an area to open:
2. The Editor menu you can select:
3. 'UV/Image Editor' where you should see:
4. Your previous render. If not:
5. Select 'Render Result' from the Image menu and also, possibly:
6. The Slot you rendered into.

[image: Steps for finding rendered image]

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about Render Slots.

Comment: This will save me SO much time.

Answer (score 4):

If you rendered to the same slot, the previous information is gone forever.

If you switched to a different slot, then the information of other slots is untouched and you can switch back and forth.

To access the rendered slots you need to be in Render Result as the source for the UV/Image window:

[image]

To save the information of any of the rendered slots, use the Save as Image option on the UV/Image editor and use OpenEXR as the format, that will keep the rendered image as scene referred data.

An alternative, is to add a File Output node in the compositor. That way every time you render you will be saving a file automatically. Note that if you render again, it will render to the same file and overwrite the previous image.

Comment: "If you switched to a different slot, then the information of other slots is untouched and you can switch back and forth." Id like to be able to get back to this without re rendering (In the same session). They must be stored in a temp file somewhere? I'd like to be able to get back to the Render Slot dropdown menu without rendering. (Say the phone rang and I wasnt ready to re render).

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking then. If you use render slot 1 to render, then you make changes and render to slot 2, the information on slot 1 is still there. and As far as I know is not saved but is just in RAM

Comment: "If you use render slot 1 to render, then you make changes and render to slot 2, the information on slot 1 is still there". Exactly, but if I leave that menu where the Render Slot dropdown is to edit I cant find a way to get back to it without making another render. Sometime I want to compare the Render Slots again before taking the time to re render.

Comment: Just go back to the UV/Image editor window, select ''Render Result'' and the Render slots should be there.

Comment: @Dontwalk see edited answer

Comment: Good answer! One thing that still bothering me is: Why there is a *Fake User* button next to the Render Result since it doesn't work? (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48862/fake-user-in-uv-editor-what-is-it-for)

Comment: I didnt ask a new question... Paul Gonet did. But I still thank you for your help.